# Hiding columns based on content of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My mission is to hide all columns in my Google Sheet, based on text/value in a single cell. The range of cells to hide are from & including column 22 ("U") to 36/"BE". If the value in a row 1 of a column is the same as the value in "J812" (ie. 812,10), then it shouldn't be hidden.

Through searching online I have put together my own solution, only issue is it shows an error when the script is complete:

> "Cell reference out of range".

I don't know how to make this error disappear.

Part of my code is derived from this question: [Google spreadsheets: Hide columns based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568425/google-spreadsheets-hide-columns-based-on-cell-value)

Here is my code:

```js
function HideColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;
  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // iterate through columns
  for(var i = 1; i < lastCol; i++) {
    if(data.getCell(1, 21 + i).getValue() !== sheet.getRange(812, 10).getValue()) {
      sheet.hideColumns(21 + i);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

lastCol is your last column + 1. In your for loop, you loop loop till lastCol. However in getCell() it is 21+i. Meaning you go 21 too far and are therefore out of range :-)

Comment: Cheers @Stefan, I can see what you mean by data.getCell(1, 21+i) going past the last column... the code as it is hides all columns ("V:BE") that have a cell in row1 that do not contain the same value/text as the "J812" (812,10)... so how then could I improve the code to not have '21+i'? I was using 21+i as my column starting point, without it the code hides all columns except those columns where the statement = false (ie. cells in row 1 from cell 21 onwards = J812).  Cheers

Comment: use i < lastCol - 21 in the for loop

Answer (score -1):

Could this work:

```
for(var i = 1; i < (lastCol-21); i++)
```

Comment: This answer just repeats the final solution worked out by Stefan van Aalst.